# Memory issues when joining dataframes in pandas (time indexed)

Tags: pandas, join, time, merge, series

I am trying to join (or merge) two dataframes in pandas which are time indexed, but my code accumulates the tables in memory.

Each file is only 1 MB and after a few files, the computer runs out of memory.

How can a do this operation in place?

The method used for joining the tables (left, right, inner, outer...) does not change the performance issue.

```
import pandas as pd
from glob import glob  

filenames = glob('*.txt')

filename = filenames[0]
varname =  filename[:-11] # removes three last char extension from string

print('Sampling', filename)
data = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=';', skiprows=3, names=['time', varname ],
               index_col=0)


for filename in filenames[1:]:

    print('Sampling', filename)

    varname =  filename[:-11] # removes three last char extension from string

    data_new = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=';', skiprows=3, names=['time', varname ],
               index_col=0)


    #data = pd.DataFrame.join(data, data_new, how='outer', on='time')
    data = pd.DataFrame.merge(data_new, data, how='outer', on='time', copy=False)
```

These are the data.head() and data.tail() after running the code for three files.

```
                    var1    var2    var3    var4    var5
time                    
01/01/2016 07:00:00 13.3781 6.95406 NaN 87.6588 71.5696
01/01/2016 08:00:00 13.2312 6.89561 NaN 87.6221 71.6038
01/01/2016 09:00:00 13.2774 6.90632 NaN 87.2595 71.4383
01/01/2016 10:00:00 13.6152 7.02360 NaN 87.2028 71.4482
01/01/2016 11:00:00 13.5584 7.00147 NaN 87.3733 71.3335
```

...

```
                    var1    var2    var3    var4    var5
time                    
01/01/2019 02:00:00 15.8096 28.2316 NaN 87.5106 68.6665
01/01/2019 03:00:00 15.8352 28.1616 NaN 87.7226 69.0639
01/01/2019 04:00:00 15.6879 27.6819 NaN 87.1135 68.6873
01/01/2019 05:00:00 15.6558 27.7961 NaN 87.4658 69.1395
01/01/2019 06:00:00 15.7383 28.1330 NaN 87.5775 68.8240
```

Comment: It would be helpful to understand the input data.  In your MCVE, you could generate example files.  Try pulling the CSV loading out of the loop that does the merge.  It will help you understand what part is causing a problem.  There is nothing inherently wrong with loading dozens of dataframes and holding them in memory prior to operating on them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the dataframes share the same index, [pd.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) performs the operation without trouble.

```
data = pd.concat([data, data_new], axis=1)
```